# TFS 2015 Gulp Build Step Gives a path length error

Tags: tfs, gulp, tfs-2015

I'm having an issue where I get the following error on my gulp build step in the TFS Console.

```
1 2016-08-31T09:52:06.2779460Z Executing the powershell script: E:\ba6\tasks\Gulp\0.5.3\Gulptask.ps1

2 2016-08-31T09:52:08.2879964Z ##[error]The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

3 2016-08-31T09:52:08.2949949Z ##[error]Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
```

And this in the _diag folder:

```
14:25:34.652188 JobRunner.Run - Running task Gulp.
14:25:34.652188 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = b72d7940-e675-41bc-844e-08a42ba432dd, message = ##[section]Starting task: npm clean up)
14:25:34.653183 JobExtensionManager.OnBeforeExecuteTask
14:25:34.653183 JobExtensionManager.OnExecuteTask
14:25:34.654208 BaseLogger.LogStatus(scope.JobId = b72d7940-e675-41bc-844e-08a42ba432dd, scope.TimelineRecordId = b558700b-923d-4d5f-8aa6-918bfd1dc374, record.Name = npm clean up)
14:25:34.655188 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = b72d7940-e675-41bc-844e-08a42ba432dd, message = Executing the powershell script: E:\ba6\tasks\Gulp\0.5.3\Gulptask.ps1)
14:25:34.656187 PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddCommand(E:\ba6\tasks\Gulp\0.5.3\Gulptask.ps1)
14:25:34.656187 PowerShellHandler.Execute - Add inputParameters
14:25:34.656187 PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(gulpFile=E:\ba6\w\1\s\LexisAdvance\gulpfile.js)
14:25:34.656187 PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(targets=npmclean)
14:25:34.656187 PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(arguments=)
14:25:34.656187 PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(cwd=E:\ba6\w\1\s\LexisAdvance)
14:25:34.723195 PowerShellHandler.Execute - Invoke
14:25:34.885161 Process logging event with task handler.
14:25:34.885161 BaseLogger.LogStatus(scope.JobId = b72d7940-e675-41bc-844e-08a42ba432dd, scope.TimelineRecordId = b558700b-923d-4d5f-8aa6-918bfd1dc374, record.Name = )
14:25:34.886161 Process logging event with task handler.
14:25:34.943163 Process logging event with task handler.
14:25:34.943163 BaseLogger.LogStatus(scope.JobId = b72d7940-e675-41bc-844e-08a42ba432dd, scope.TimelineRecordId = b558700b-923d-4d5f-8aa6-918bfd1dc374, record.Name = )
14:25:34.943163 Process logging event with task handler.
14:25:34.975164 Invoke - Get-TaskVariable cmdlet
14:25:34.981164 FindFiles.FindMatchingFiles(rootFolder = , matchPattern = E:\ba6\w\1\s\**\gulp.cmd, includeFiles = True, includeFolders = False
14:25:34.984164 FindFiles.GetMatchingItems(includePatterns.Count = 1, excludePatterns.Count = 0, includeFiles = True, includeFolders = False
14:25:35.042166 FindFiles.GetMatchingItems - Found: E:\ba6\w\1\s\LexisAdvance\node_modules\.bin\gulp.cmd
14:25:37.626247 Process logging event with task handler.
14:25:37.626247 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = b72d7940-e675-41bc-844e-08a42ba432dd, message = ##[error]The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.)
14:25:37.632248 Process logging event with task handler.
14:25:37.632248 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = b72d7940-e675-41bc-844e-08a42ba432dd, message = ##[error]Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.)
14:25:37.634249 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Common.AgentExecutionTerminationException: PowerShell script completed with errors.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.PowerShellHandler.Execute(ITaskContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.RunTask(ITaskContext context, TaskWrapper task, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
14:25:37.634249 Process logging event with task handler.
14:25:37.634249 BaseLogger.LogStatus(scope.JobId = b72d7940-e675-41bc-844e-08a42ba432dd, scope.TimelineRecordId = b558700b-923d-4d5f-8aa6-918bfd1dc374, record.Name = )
14:25:37.635247 BaseLogger.LogAttachment(scope.JobId = b72d7940-e675-41bc-844e-08a42ba432dd, type = DistributedTask.Core.Log, name = npm clean up, path = E:\ba6\_diag\wa66f1583-e1a1-487e-b110-41917853afef.log)
14:25:37.635247 JobExtensionManager.OnAfterExecuteTask
14:25:37.635247 Process logging event with context handler.
14:25:37.635247 BaseLogger.LogStatus(scope.JobId = b72d7940-e675-41bc-844e-08a42ba432dd, scope.TimelineRecordId = b558700b-923d-4d5f-8aa6-918bfd1dc374, record.Name = )
14:25:37.635247 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = b72d7940-e675-41bc-844e-08a42ba432dd, message = ##[section]Finishing task: Gulp)
```

There doesn't seem to be any thing that says where the problem folder is.

I have tried to shorten the paths as much as I can but nothing seems to fix the issue.

This is the GULP Setup

[image]

The NPM version is 3.10.6

[image]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of gulp build step setting?

Comment: have you gotten around to it? i'm having the same issue..